# Purpose of using API Key in addition to password

Tags: appsec, key-management, api

It was suggested to my coworker and me to password protect our API in addition to requiring an API key. This doesn't seem like it's making anything safer since if the threat gained access to our API key, presumably they also gained access to the password.

Is this standard practice to secure with both an API key and password? I've searched around but haven't seen anything suggesting to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of an API key is to authenticate (or at least identify) the application, and not the user. Something called an “API key” does not normally determine what data a request is allowed to access, but how many requests can be made in a certain time interval through a given user account. It's a way to impose access quotas, to avoid denial of service, without completely blocking a user just because they've used a buggy app or have used it a little more than you'd like.

If your API serves public data then there's no reason to have a password in addition to the API key. The API key is the password, in this case.

Comment: Gotcha. So if I'm interpreting you right, if I have a membership based API, I would want to have a password in addition to the key?